# Open multiple predefined text files in python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, text

Hello I was just wondering if it was possible to open multiple predefined text files in python.

I have some code below (it doesn't work yet), and the first function has a parameter of categories, which are all text file names that are predefined below in a test case. I need to try and open all of the text files as defined below to input them into an sql database.

```
data_entry(categories):
    with open ((categories)"*.txt"), "r") as categories:
        lines = categories.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        data = line.split()
        number = data[0]
        value = data[1]

    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO popularity (PersonNumber, category, value)
                    VALUES(%s, %s, %s)""", (number, category, value))    

if __name__ == '__main__':
        data_entry(['movies', 'sports', 'actors', 'tv', 'games', \
        'activities', 'musicians', 'books'])
```

Is this possible? If so, how would I go about getting this to work how I need?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use string interpolation or formatting to put the category into the filespec, and `glob.glob()` to resolve it.

Comment: I'm a little nooby at python sorry, is there any chance for a little more explanation? :\

Comment: [String Formatting Operations](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations), [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you reading the lines into a list, and then going over it after the fact?

```
import glob, itertools

def data_entry(categories):
    globs = [glob.iglob(category + "*.txt") for category in categories]
    for filename in itertools.chain(*globs):
        with open(filename) as f:
            for line in f:
                number, value = line.split()

                cursor.execute(...)
```

[`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain); [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html); [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 0):

Python is not Perl, so you should write code that is easier to read, even if is a little bit longer. Also the the new with syntax is available only on newer pythons.

You should be able to adapt this sequence to your code

```
import fnmatch
import os

for file in os.listdir('.'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.txt'):
        print(file)
```

Or just:

```
data_entry(categories):
    foreach category in categories:
        f = open ("%s.txt" % (category)), "r")
```